# Install Mist Ethereum on external HDD

Tags: mist, blockchain, installation, keystore, hardware

The question is simple though I can't find a solution to this - how do I keep all ethereum-related files on an external hard disk drive?

I would like to have the blockchain data, keystore and Mist launch files to be on an external HDD that can be easily moved/connected to another PC etc.